# How to use concatenate in os.rename with Python

Tags: python, concatenation, rename

I'd like to concatenate variables using os.rename.
I'm only aware of very basic concatenate methods like 'format' or '%s,%d etc'

```
os.rename(r'mypath/name.csv',r'mypath/new_name.csv')
```

What should I use ?
Is os.rename even that useful ?

Comment: Just a note `os.rename` is used to rename the file on your file system(Not indented to format the strings)

Comment: What do you mean by concatenate in this context? What is your desired output?

Comment: Please provide the some sample input and output for such a concatenation!

Comment: You can just do `os.rename(r'mypath/name.csv', r'mypath/%s.csv' % (newFileName));` if that's what you're looking for. It's simple and easy to use.

Comment: %s Worked. I must have been using it the wrong way...Thanks

Comment: Another issue appeared... I can't concatenate many variables. os.rename(r'mypath/{0}.xls', r'mypath/{1}.xls'.format (var1, var2)). Python recognizes the Var2 but cant find my file with {0} and var1. There is no difference between them...I don't get it.